# add prefix namespace only in xsd:schema with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

i'm trying to add to my `xsd:schema` the following prefix `xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm"` without changing nothing of my XSD document.
I tried this :

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
 <xsl:element name="nr0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
 </xsl:element>    
</xsl:template>
```

But it creates two problems : 
1 - My schema becomes invalid as the name is changed into :`<nr0:schema xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema">`

2 - All my elements I created in XML schema have been erased.

How can i keep my elements and just add the prefix to my root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, your code is currently creating an element, when you really want to create a namespace declaration.

What you can do, is simply create a new `xsd:schema` element with the required namespace declaration, and also copy all existing ones too.

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
  <xsd:schema xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsd:schema>   
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you can use XSLT 2.0, you could use `xsl:namespace` and do this...

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:namespace name="nr0" select="'http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm'" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```

(`xsl:copy` copies the existing namespaces in this case)

For your second issue, you need to add the identity template to your stylesheet, if you haven't already

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
      <xsd:schema xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsd:schema>   
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Alternative code for XSLT 2.0 -->
    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:namespace name="nr0" select="'http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm'" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```